# complex annotation in django query

Tags: django

Current state:

model.py

```
class Foo(models.model):
  name =  models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True, unique = True)

class Item(models.model):
  foo = models.ForeignKey('Foo')
  number =  models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
  stats= Foo.objects.filter(somecond=somevalue).\
  annotate(count=Count('item__number'), max=Max('item__number'))

  return render_to_response('stats.html', {'stats' : stats})
```

And the result as expected is the list of objects Foo with additional fields: count containing the count of items related with Foo and max - the max number of item.

example:

```
Item1: Foo1, 12
Item2: Foo2, 100
Item3: Foo1, 10
Item4: Foo2, 78
Item5: Foo1, 6
```

Result:

stats:

```
Foo1, 3, 12
Foo2, 2, 100
```

Allright.
Now I'd like to get more:

```
class sell(models.Model):
  foo = models.ForeignKey('Foo')
  value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
```

filled with:

```
sell1: Foo1, 12.50
sell2: Foo2, 12.40
sell3: Foo1,  4.12
sell4: Foo2, 10.00



stats=Foo.objects.filter(somecond=somevalue).\
annotate(Count('item__number'), Max('item__number'), Sum('sell__value'))
```

My expectation is:

stats:

```
Foo1, 3, 12, 16.62
Foo2, 2, 100, 22.40
```

but the result is some kind of multiplication of number of items and values (e.g. if the sell element is one, and there is four Foos, the sum is 4*sell.value)

I also tried Sum('sell__value', distinct=True) but no difference.

I wanted it for template, where I want to do for loop with stats

```
{% for foo in stats %}
<h2>{{ foo.name }} </h2>
{{foo.count}}/{{foo.max}} 
sum of sell related with foo
{{foo.sum}}
```

that's way I want to insert sum into stats.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility you can find https://stackoverflow.com/a/40443262/354420

You have to create own Manager with own QuerySet:

and then

```
both = Foo.objects.annotate_sum(Sell, 'value')
```

Answer (score 0):

I choose the solution

```
stats=Foo.objects.filter(somecond=somevalue).annotate(Count('item__number'), Max('item__number')).in_bulk()
sells=Foo.objects.filter(somecond=somevalue).annotate(Sum('sell__value')).in_bulk()
for key, stat in stats.items():
  setattr(stat,'sell__value__sum',sells[key].sell__value__sum)
```

I know that in_bulk() calls two sqls, but this isn't problem for me. My other answer calls one sql.