# how to merge two annotated querysets into one result

Tags: django

Model:

```
class Foo(models.model):
  name =  models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True, unique = True)

class Bar1(models.Model):
  foo = models.ForeignKey('Foo')
  value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)

class Bar2(models.Model):
  foo = models.ForeignKey('Foo')
  value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
```

Clasess Bar1 and Bar2 are unrelated, so I can't do it as one class what would solve the problem. But this is only example to show the problem as pure as possible.

```
first = Foo.objects.all().annotate(Sum("bar1__value"))
second = Foo.objects.all().annotate(Sum("bar2__value"))
```

each of this querysets contains correct values.

I can't merge it into:

```
 both = Foo.objects.all().annotate(Sum("bar1__value")).annotate(Sum("bar2__value"))
```

Because the sum value multiplicates - this is unfortunately expected behaviour - because of JOINS

And now the problem - how to merge/join first and second to get the both?

Example:

Bar 1:

```
  foo | value
--------------
   A  |  10
   B  |  20
   B  |  20
```

Bar 2:

```
  foo | value
--------------
   A  |  -0.10
   A  |  -0.10
   B  |  -0.25
```

both (value differs depends on order of entering bar1 and bar2)

```
  foo | bar1__value__sum | bar2__value__sum
---------------------------------
   A  |  20              | -0.20
   B  |  40              | -0.50
```

expected result:

```
  foo | bar1__value__sum | bar2__value__sum
---------------------------------
   A  |  10              | -0.20
   B  |  40              | -0.25
```

I couldn't use itertools.chains because the result is:

```
  foo | bar1__value__sum | bar2__value__sum
---------------------------------
   A  |  null            | -0.20
   B  |  null            | -0.25
   A  |  10              | null
   B  |  40              | null
```

Comment: couldn't reproduce using latest Django 1.10.3

Comment: @madzohan please check updated code now

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a known limitation of Django's ORM: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060.

If you're ok with doing two queries, here's one option:

```
result = Foo.objects.annotate(b1_sum=Sum("bar1__value"))
bar2_sums = Foo.objects.annotate(b2_sum=Sum("bar2__value")).in_bulk()
for foo in result:
    foo.b2_sum = bar2_sums.get(foo.pk).b2_sum
```

Comment: It's ok with doing two queries, but I'm not sure how this would work. result after for is the same as result before. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, the example had several typos (fixed now). The idea is to annotate the instances in `result` manually: when you iterate over it again, you'll get the same annotated instances from the queryset cache. Instead of in_bulk you can also just get the `values()` you need and use a dict comprehension.

Comment: Yes it works, I looked at djangoproject's ticket and found other solution - now i'm trying to analyze it. After that I choose the better answer ;D

Comment: When I used this from within a view's `get_queryset`, returning `result` does not have a `b2_sum` field attached. (using Django 2.0.6)

Answer (score 0):

According to answer of @emulbreh i read the ticket and found some solution. I go this way and made this:

models.py:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
(...)
class NewManager(models.Manager):
  """A re-usable Manager to access a custom QuerySet"""
  def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
    try:
      return getattr(self.__class__, attr, *args)
    except AttributeError:
    # don't delegate internal methods to the queryset
      if attr.startswith('__') and attr.endswith('__'):
        raise
      return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args)

  def get_query_set(self):
    return self.model.QuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)


class Foo(models.Model):
  name =  models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True, unique = True)
  objects =NewManager()
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

  class QuerySet(QuerySet):
    def annotate_sum(self, modelClass, field_name):
      annotation_name="%s__%s__%s" % (modelClass._meta.model_name,field_name,'sum')
      raw_query = "SELECT SUM({field}) FROM {model2} WHERE {model2}.{model3}_id = {model1}.id".format(
              field = field_name,
              model3 = self.model._meta.model_name,
              model2 = modelClass._meta.db_table,
              model1 = self.model._meta.db_table
          )
      debug.debug("%s" % raw_query)
      annotation = {annotation_name: RawSQL(raw_query, [])}

      return self.annotate(**annotation)
```

And views.py:

```
both = Foo.objects.annotate_sum(Bar1, 'value').annotate_sum( Bar2, 'value')
```

the sql result is exact what I want:

```
SELECT "app_foo"."id", "app_foo"."name", (SELECT SUM(value) FROM app_bar1 WHERE app_bar1.foo_id = app_foo.id) AS "bar1__value__sum", (SELECT SUM(value) FROM app_bar2 WHERE app_bar2.foo_id = app_foo.id) AS "bar2__value__sum" FROM "app_foo"
```

Of course it isn't perfect - it needs some error checking (e.g. double quotes) or aliases, but i think this is the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this page after having a similar problem, but with `Count` instead of `Sum`.

The simplest solution is to use `Count(<field>, distinct=True)` on the 2nd `Count`, i.e.

```
both = Foo.objects.all().annotate(Count("bar1__value")
                       ).annotate(Count("bar2__value", distinct=True))
```

References:

- [ticket 10060/comment:60](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060#comment:60) linked by @emulbreh answer
- django 2.0 docs / Aggregation # [Combining multiple aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations)